# Which option to choose for designing this API endpoint

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-boot, api-design

Let's imagine we have an API endpoint: /cars/1 and this returns basic information about the car (id, name, description).

But we can also request GET /cars/1?info=extra and this will also return extra information about the car (price, stock). And this extra information is stored in our Database as another table, which has a One To One relationship with the Car.

If it helps, our backend is a Java Spring Boot application.

There are many ways to return the data. Would you return same objects in both requests, with the corresponding extra parameters as null in the ?info=extra request? Or would you return different objects for each one of the requests?

For me returning all the nulls when requesting the "basic" info has the advantage of using the same Class to map both requests, by only changing the @Query in the JPA Repository, making it easier to maintain.

Returning all the nulls also has the disadvantage of returning a lot of useless values that the user didn't even requested. It also makes the API more difficult to read (someone can think that all of those values are actually null and they might not). Speaking of classes, we would have a MappedSuperClass Car and two other classes CarBasic and CarExtra, both extending Car, each one of them with the corresponding getters to create the output JSON.

**Option 1:**

/cars/1

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Honda Civic",
    description: "The best car of Honda"
}
```

/cars/1?info=extra

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Honda Civic",
    description: "The best car of Honda",
    extraInfo: {
    {
        price: 25000,
        stock: 24
    }
}
```

**Option 2:**

/cars/1

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Honda Civic",
    description: "The best car of Honda",
    extraInfo: null
}
```

/cars/1?info=extra

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Honda Civic",
    description: "The best car of Honda",
    extraInfo: {
    {
        price: 25000,
        stock: 24
    }
}
```

**Option 3:**

/cars/1

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Honda Civic",
    description: "The best car of Honda"
}
```

/cars/1?info=extra

```
{
    id: 1,
    name: "Honda Civic",
    description: "The best car of Honda",
    price: 25000,
    stock: 24
}
```

What do you think?

Comment: I like Option 3,  but with the addition of your other classes,  but i lean towards consistency.  How would you be planning to return the specific information that is contained with the child classes?

Comment: Do you mean that for the basic, return option 1, and for the extra, return option 2?

Comment: We don't know exact context. If you create API you should clearly understand what you should get as an result. For example, if you have some UI and you would like to fill some table with columns "id", "name", "description", "price", "stock" and this is only one thing for which you need API endpoint I would suggest option 3 with endpoint `/cars/1`, but JSON: `{
    id: 1,
    name: "Honda Civic",
    description: "The best car of Honda",
    price: 25000,
    stock: 24
}`. About null value, there is a rule "Don't show more information than needed" or at least show `{}` instead of null.

Comment: personally, I maintain API request params also in the response. So that front end can decide and parse response accordingly. like 
 `{ params: { info: true, extraInfo: false }, data: { id: 1, name: "Honda Civic", desc: "blah blah", meta: {price: 25000, stock: 24 }}}`

Answer (score -1):

However not really a StackOverflow type of question, a very interesting one nonetheless.

Personally I would prefer option 3.

In terms of code you could even extend your normal `Car` class with a model with your extra fields.

Comment: I like that option too. However, in terms of maintainability, if some day we want to add the parameter info=extraPrices, we can't extend from CarExtra, as in JPA is not that easy. We would have to create a CarExtraPrices that extends from Car again, duplicating the extra fields already present in CarExtra.

Answer (score -1):

Just consider the frontend, i think the option 1 is better.

But it also needs to be consider the backend, how do you achieve the basic info and the extraInfo.

In addition, i think you can take a look at [graphql](http://graphql.org/) and [graphql-java](https://github.com/graphql-java).Hope it helps.